# Nullable Guid to Null during JSON Deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net

**Update:** with the help of the answers below, I was able to see the error in my code and fix the problem.

I'm trying to figure out why a `GUID?` is being set to null during deserialization.  I first saw this when `parentStepId` was set to null in the POST of my WebApi.  I verified that the JSON has the correct value for `parentStepId` on the client side.  To help track down what the problem is, I created a `JsonConverter`.    In the `JsonConverter` I can see that the JSON has the correct values before the conversion, but after the conversion `parentStepId` is set to null even though it has a valid `GUID` in the JSON.

So what could be causing this or how can I work around this?

On the client before the Ajax call is made and in the `JsonConverter`, the JSON looks like:

```
{
  "parentStepId": "c9ddfd7e-d124-e511-922d-ecf4bb4dc732",
  "workflowStep": {
    "enabled": true,
    "title": "9",
    "persistent": true,
    "extendable": false,
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "removeThisEntity": false,
    "deleteThisEntity": false,
    "serializeForServer": true
  },
  "order": 1,
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "removeThisEntity": false,
  "deleteThisEntity": false,
  "serializeForServer": true
}
```

Here's the `ReadJson` of the converter:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        //parentStepId is the expected value here
        var tmpVal = jObject == null ? string.Empty : jObject.ToString();

        //parentStepId is set to null during this deserialization.
        var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderedWorkflow_WorkflowStep>(tmpVal);

        return res;
    }
```

and the `OrderedWorkflow_WorkflowStep` class:

```
public class OrderedWorkflow_WorkflowStep : TbdOrderedEntity
{
    public Guid? ParentWorkflowId { get; set; }

    public virtual WorkflowStep WorkflowStep { get; set; }

    public Guid? WorkflowStepId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class does not correctly map the JSON provided.

*There is no `workflowStepId` (or `parentWorkflowId`) in the JSON* - JSON.Net does not know how to map the fields and thus *the properties will retain their default values*. If they had been non-nullable they would have been all-zero GUIDs.

The [various annotations](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) can apply basic transformations - such as using different field names which should probably be `id` and `parentStepId`, respectively. For example:

```
public class OrderedWorkflow_WorkflowStep : TbdOrderedEntity
{
    [JsonProperty("parentStepId")]
    public Guid? ParentWorkflowId { get; set; }

    public virtual WorkflowStep WorkflowStep { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]    
    public Guid? WorkflowStepId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I have a similar class and I got the names mixed up.  I've been looking at this for so long I couldn't see the mistake even though it was right in front of me...